# How to handle reset behaviour when escape character is pressed twice in Orbeon Xforms

Tags: html, escaping, reset, orbeon, xforms

I have come to know that from IE 5, there is a strange behaviour that when escape character is pressed twice, all the form fields are reset automatically. This is not occuring in Mozilla. So as a remedy i have put a simple javascript that will alert user when values are getting reset. Below is the code for it.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="Enroll" method="post" onreset="return confirm('Really reset all form  fields?')">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name </td>
<td><input type="text" id="name"/></td>
<td>Id </td>
<td><input type="text" id="id"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, please help me how i can acheive this is Orbeon Xforms as this is happening in Orbeon xforms also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This used to be a [bug](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/131), and it has been [fixed](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/5af48e7a94014efb56bf0fc432663e9a9e5fcfcf) on 2012-04-20, and the fix is available in nightly builds and releases made after that date.

Comment: This issue is now fixed, and I updated the answer accordingly.